# The most frequent in column of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3-column dataframe, where 3-rd (last) contains text body, something like one sentence.

Additionally I have one vector of words.
How to compute in elegant way a following thing:

> find 15 the most frequent words (with number of occurences) in whole
>   3-rd column which occur in mentioned above vector  ?

The sentence can look like:
`I like dogs and my father like cats`
`vector=["dogs", "like"]`
Here, the most frequent words are `dogs` and `like`.

Comment: @markus consider it done!

Comment: How is 'dogs' the most frequent.  It is only occuring once

Comment: Ok, however I would like to know 15 most frequent (the most frequent, almost the most frequent). Example was simplified.

Comment: Please provide a proper example with proper data structures. There is no data frame in this question as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%                           # your data
unnest_tokens(word,text) %>%     # clean a bit the data and split the phrases
group_by(word) %>%               # grouping by words
summarise(Freq = n()) %>%        # count them
arrange(-Freq) %>%               # order decreasing
top_n(2)                         # here the top 2, you can use 15
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  word   Freq
  <chr> <int>
1 dogs      3
2 i         2
```

If you already have the words splitted, you can skip the second line.

---

With data:

```
df <- data.frame(
id = c(1,2,3),
group = c(1,1,1),
text = c("I like dogs","I don't hate dogs", "dogs are the best"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```